# Old Putnam problem that I could use some help on

Tags: functions, contest-math, analytic-geometry

I've been beginning to practice for the Putnam this year, and I came across a
problem from a few years back that I could use some help on. I want to find the
values of $\alpha$ for which the curves $y = \alpha x^2 + \alpha x +
\frac{1}{24}$ and $x = \alpha y^2 + \alpha y + \frac{1}{24}$ are tangent to
each other.

Hence, I believe that what I am looking for is all of the $\alpha$s such that
the defined curves intersect at one point and only one point (based on the
tangential aspect of this problem). Say this point is $(x_1,y_1)$ we need to
show that this point uniquely satisfies
$y_1 = \alpha x_1^2 + \alpha x_1 + \frac{1}{24}$ and
$x_1 = \alpha y_1^2 + \alpha y_1 + \frac{1}{24}.$ What I had imagined that we
would need to do is plug one equation into the other, and find the $\alpha$s
such that the given equation has only one root (although, this is primarily
just a hypothesis of what may work). So far, I set
$$y_1 = \alpha (\alpha y_1^2 + \alpha y_1 + \frac{1}{24})^2
+ \alpha (\alpha y_1^2 + \alpha y_1 + \frac{1}{24}) + \frac{1}{24}$$
Although I am having some difficulties figuring out what may be the best way
to manner to simplify this equation, given that it will end up having one side
with a polynomial of degree $4$ (which seems somewhat unweildy). Any
recommendations?

Comment: You might want to use that the tangent lines at an intersection point are parallel.

Comment: Discussion of many (all?) old Putnam problems should be at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C_1:y=\alpha x^2+\alpha x+\frac1{24}$$
$$C_2:x=\alpha y^2+\alpha y+\frac1{24}$$
$$L:y=x$$
$x$ and $y$ are swapped between the two equations, so $C_1$ is the reflection of $C_2$ across $L$ and vice versa.

There can be at most four intersections with multiplicity (IM) between $C_1$ and $C_2$. If $C_1$ does not cross $L$, there are no intersections/tangencies at all; if it does, there cannot be a distinct pair of tangencies across $L$ since that would make for more than four IMs. Hence all tangencies must lie on $L$.

Furthermore, the tangent directions at tangencies must be parallel (A) or perpendicular (B) to $L$. For case (A):
$$x=\alpha x^2+\alpha x+\frac1{24}$$
$$\alpha x^2+(\alpha-1)x+\frac1{24}=0$$
If the discriminant of this polynomial is zero, $C_1$ will be tangent to $L$ and thus to $C_2$:
$$(\alpha-1)^2-4\alpha\cdot\frac1{24}=0$$
$$\alpha^2-2\alpha+1-\frac16\alpha=0$$
$$\alpha^2-\frac{13}6\alpha+1=0$$
Solving for $\alpha$ we get
$$\alpha=\frac23\text{ or }\alpha=\frac32$$
For case (B), if the derivative of $C_1$ where it meets $L$ is $-1$, it will also be tangent to $C_2$ (on the same side) by symmetry:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\alpha x+\alpha=-1$$
$$x=\frac{-\alpha-1}{2\alpha}$$
$$\alpha x^2+(\alpha-1)x+\frac1{24}=0\to\alpha\left(\frac{-\alpha-1}{2\alpha}\right)^2+(\alpha-1)\frac{-\alpha-1}{2\alpha}+\frac1{24}=0$$
$$\frac{(\alpha+1)^2}{4\alpha^2}-(\alpha-1)\frac{\alpha+1}{2\alpha^2}+\frac1{24\alpha}=0$$
$$(\alpha+1)^2-2(\alpha-1)(\alpha+1)+\frac16\alpha=0$$
$$\alpha^2+2\alpha+1-2\alpha^2+2+\frac16\alpha=0$$
$$-\alpha^2+\frac{13}6\alpha+3=0$$
$$6\alpha^2-13\alpha-18=0$$
Solving for $\alpha$ we get
$$\alpha=\frac{13\pm\sqrt{601}}{12}$$

---

In conclusion, the values of $\alpha$ where both curves are tangent to each other are
$$\alpha=\frac23,\frac32,\frac{13\pm\sqrt{601}}{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the difference of the two functions giving the curves. At a point of intersection $(x,y)$, 
$$
x-y = ay^2 - ax^2 +ay - ax.
$$
See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Extended hint (too long for a comment).

Curves $y = P(x)$ and $x = P(y)$ are symmetric with respect to $y = x$. They can have at most $4$ intersection points (counting multiplicities) because of the degrees of the polynomials involved.

- If one of them doesn't intersect $y = x$ then neither will the other, because each one will be strictly contained in either half plane separated by $y = x$, So this case can be ignored.
- If one of them does intersect $y = x$ then that would be an intersection point with its mirror image, and there can be no tangency points outside $y = x$, because its symmetric with respect to $y = x$ would also be a tangency point, and that would give a total of $1+2+2=5 \gt 4$ intersection points (again, counting multiplicities).

Therefore, any points of tangency must be on the axis of symmetry $y = x$, which gives:

$$
(1) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; P(x) = x \;\;\iff\;\; \alpha x^2 + \alpha x + \frac{1}{24}= x
$$

Furthermore, the tangents must be the same, but the only lines invariant to the symmetry across $y = x$ are $y = x$ itself and the normals $y = -x + y_0$. Therefore:

$$
(2) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; P'(x) = \pm 1 \;\;\iff\;\; 2 \alpha x + \alpha = \pm 1
$$

Eliminating $x$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$ results in two quadratics in $\alpha$, which happen to have real and distinct roots each, so in the end there are $4$ solutions for $\alpha$.